# Ruby on Rails Parts of Website with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am creating a web site with rails. I am planning to have some of the content of the web site fetched via ajax.

For example, parts like the "Recent Inbox Messages" on stackoverflow are fetched using ajax it seems. What I plan to do is to have a profile button at the top right corner and when the user mouses over it, I fetch the options (logout etc..).

What is the rails compliant way of doing this? What are the class structures that I should follow?

For example, do I have a ProfileMenuController and use that class to handle the AJAX calls? How about the routing and the template(.erb) files?

PS :- It is not about how to do AJAX with rails. I'm asking about the class structure etc. The Rails AJAX guides on the web would show examples of maybe creating REST resources fetching resources etc.. What I want to know for example is, do we create a separate controller just to handle the profile menu? Or is there another way which rails supports this kind of functionality?

Comment: This is way too broad for a SO question. The Rails guide to AJAX may help you - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Comment: @sevenseacat I edited the question and added more explanation. Maybe now it is not too broad?

Comment: The question would probably lead to opinion-based answers, which is a problem for many SO people (hence the close flag by someone)

Answer (score 2):

If you're wanting to add something like notifications or other "live" functionality to your site, you'll not be able to achieve it with ajax alone

[Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) only handles requests you *send* to the server; it can't "listen" to updates from the server

---

**text/event-stream**

You're looking for a way to "listen" to `text/event-stream` `content-type` content from the server. The only way to do this is to either use [`SSE`'s (`Server Sent Events`)](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp), or [`websockets`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp). Both of these technologies use Javascript, but "listen" for updates, rather than sending them directly

The way it works is to use javascript to create a "connection" to the server, and then your web framework will "send" updates encoded in the `text/event-stream` content-type to the listeners. The way you provide data for private individuals is to use the [pub/sub pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) (create different channels)

I can detail how you'd do this with Rails if you want - leave a comment if you want!

There's also a great tutorial here describing it: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/

Comment: Couldn't you poll the server with an AJAX get request at regular intervals (e.g. every minute) and get updates that way? Might be a simpler solution depending on his exact needs.

Comment: Yep that's called Ajax long polling. It's quite inefficient, which is why I didn't recommend it